# Python FlasK Mail. 4.3.2 Concurrent connections limit exceeded

Tags: outlook, smtp, smtplib, flask-mail

I am trying to send mail using python flask_mail module.
The email I am using is hosted/created by godady outlook. It is able to send email successfully. However, when there are multiple users that trigger sending of email functions, I get the following error:

```
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (432, b'4.3.2 Concurrent connections limit exceeded. Visit https://aka.ms/concurrent_sending for more information. [Hostname=H...apcprd04.prod.outlook.com]')
```

How do I go about solving this issue? I was thinking if this is server imposed limit, I have to somehow queue the email sending function call, and send email one by one.